# Visibility on include tag?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an XML like:

```
<FrameLayout>
   ...
   <include layout="..." id="@+id/myId">
   ...
</FrameLayout>
```

in my code however, it seems I cannot do something like

`myId.setVisible(Visiblity.GONE)`

This does not work for the `<include>` but it works for regular `TextView` for example. How can I approach this?

Comment: `TextView` element should be the root of your included XML layout file. Can you show it too?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to toggle the visibility of the included layout.

Java

```
View myId = findViewById<View>(R.id.myId);
myId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Kotlin

```
findViewById<View>(R.id.myId).visibility = View.GONE
```

The key differences in the my answer and OP are:

- The `GONE` flag should come from the `View` class instead of the `Visiblity`.
- The `setVisible()` function should be `setVisibility()`